# How do I configure Tomcat to redirect two paths to two other different applications

Tags: apache, tomcat, configuration-files

How do I configure Tomcat to redirect the following:

- https://localhost:8080/app1 to http://localhost:15000/
- https://localhost:8080/app1/abc to http://localhost:15000/abc
- https://localhost:8080/app2 to http://localhost:22000/
- https://localhost:8080/app2/abc to http://localhost:22000/abc

?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that not Tomcat needs to be configured in this way, but instead I needed to install Apache in addition to Tomcat and configure Apache with mod_rewrite and just write a simple rewrite rule.